# access AWS S3 with custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been using `AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN = 'media.example.com'`

One consequence is that I have database records of image urls which have the above domain name enbeded such as `http://media.example.com/media/blog_image_web/2016-07-01/702ef913-ddeb-4880-a715-397ce7b9efd7.jpg`

Now I'd like to stop using cloudfront and just want to server from S3.

Problem is S3 url looks like `http://my.bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/media/blog_image_web/2016-07-01/702ef913-ddeb-4880-a715-397ce7b9efd7.jpg` for the same image file..

I can update the database by replacing
`http://media.example.com/` to `http://my.bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/`

However, it would be much better if I can just keep using `http://media.example.com/` whether I use cloudfront or not (or I could move my bucket later).

How can I use a custom domain to access s3 objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a **custom domain** to point to an Amazon S3 bucket.

The basic steps are:

- **Create an S3 bucket** with a name equal to the domain name (eg `media.example.com`)
- Activate **Static Website Hosting** on the bucket
- Create an `A` record in Route 53 for `media.example.com` with `Alias = YES` and point it to your S3 website endpoint

See documentation: [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)